# Инвертирование номера

Tags: c

```
for (i = 1; numero >= i; i++) {
    for (k = i; k < numero; k++) {
        printf("*");
    }
    for (g = 1; g <= i; g++) {
        printf("%i", g);
    }
    for (g = 1; g <= i; g++) {
        printf("%i", g);
    }
    for (k = i; k < numero; k++) {
        printf("*");
    }
}
```

Если вписываю в программу 5, данная программа выводит, к примеру, вот такое чудо

```
****11****
***1212***
**123123***
*12341234*
1234512345
```

Нужно, чтобы вместо повторения инвертировало номера.Решение не бросайте, подскажите, как сделать! Благодарю.

Comment: К примеру 
****1*****
***1221***
**123321**
*12344321*
1234554321

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (i = 1; numero >= i; i++) {
    for (k = i; k < numero; k++) {
        printf("*");
    }
    for (g = 1; g <= i; g++) {
        printf("%i", g);
    }
    for (g = i; g > 0; g--) {  // <== исправлено здесь
        printf("%i", g);
    }
    for (k = i; k < numero; k++) {
        printf("*");
    }
    printf("\n");  // <== ну и перевод строки
}
```